# MongoDb deployment at multiple regions on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, aggregation-framework

Can anyone please help me to deploy the mongodb at multiple regions on GCP cloud as virtual machines. I was able to deploy the mongodb on a single region with multiple nodes but my project requirement is the deployment on multiple regions(US, HK, UK).
I was able to find this can be achieved by 'mongodb atlas' but we are using 'mongodb' as virtual machines. If anyone can suggest how this can be achieved on multiple regions without mongodb atlas, that will be very helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Did deploy your server?
If you success to deploy on same region you only have to move nodes in different regions and adapt network stuffs.
The point is about the latency between your regions. Think that it will depends on your data and ops and can penalize oplogs.